# Dismiss a view when clicking outside of the view swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a very simple view that just has a button. When the button is clicked it displays a custom picker that I made at the bottom of the screen. I would like to be able to hide the picker if the user taps anywhere outside the picker area. The very simple fix would be to just add a dismiss button to the picker but I don't like how that looks.

The button

```
struct SetBubble: View {
    @State var reps : Int = 0
    @State var weight : Int = 0
    @State var showPicker : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Button(action: {self.showPicker.toggle()}) {
                VStack{
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(reps) + "/")
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text(String(weight))
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            //Picker
            GeometryReader{geo -> CustomPicker in
                return CustomPicker(repsSelection: self.$reps, weightSelection: self.$weight, showPicker: self.$showPicker)
            }
            .offset(x: 60, y: 500)
            .opacity(self.showPicker ? 1 : 0.0)
        }
        
    }
}
```

The Picker

```
struct CustomPicker: View {
    @Binding var repsSelection : Int
    @Binding var weightSelection : Int
    @Binding var showPicker : Bool
    
    let repsAllowed = [Int](0...99)
    let weightAllowed = [Int](0...999)
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            
            Picker("Reps", selection: self.$repsSelection) {
                ForEach(0..<repsAllowed.count) {index in
                    Text("\(self.repsAllowed[index])")
                }
            }
            .frame(width:50)
            .clipped()
            Text("Reps")
            
            Picker("Weight", selection: self.$weightSelection) {
                ForEach(0..<weightAllowed.count) {index in
                    if index % 5 == 0 {
                        Text("\(self.weightAllowed[index])")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(width:50)
            .clipped()
            Text("Weight")
            
            
        }
        
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Button View]

[image: View after you click the button to display picker]

Comment: you can get the @State var showPicker : Bool = false to the outside and add a tap gesture where in the super/parent view and then pass the showPicker as binding to ur button.

Comment: That worked. I added the on tap gesture and that did the trick. Thank you!